# React Native moment.locale does not work

Tags: react-native, locale, momentjs

I am working with React Native version 0.45.1 and with moment version 2.18.1.

I am trying to change the date according to the device local, but I always get the date in 'en-Us' locale.
I can't import all of the locales as I saw in some solutions since I don't know the device locale in advance.
(for example: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2962)

any other options?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> I can't import all of the locales as I saw in some solutions since I don't know the device locale in advance.

Actually, you can [import all of the locales](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1875#issuecomment-263220119) in moment like this (`moment-with-locales` is mentioned right there on the [homepage](https://momentjs.com)):

```
import moment from 'moment/min/moment-with-locales'
// Or if you are using require instead:
var moment = require('moment/min/moment-with-locales')
```

Then you should be able to get your device locale with whatever module/method you prefer (in my example, I'll be using [Expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v19.0.0/sdk/util.html)) and change the moment locale to it. For example:

```
var deviceLocale = await Expo.Util.getCurrentLocaleAsync()
moment.locale(deviceLocale)
```

I won't say that importing everything is the best method for handling this as `moment-with-locales` is larger than just `moment`, but it does what you want it to accomplish. You can also go the route of just importing the locales you support as mentioned in that Github comment I linked to.

Comment: I thought of that - but I don't like that direction. importing everything into the application is not the best way in my mind or the correct approached when writing to mobile deivces.
for now, removed the package 'moment' and I am using Date object with 'toLocaleDateString' method to convert the date to the proper format.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of importing locale by locale, I'm using this solution to set the locale globally:

```
import { getDeviceLocale } from "react-native-device-info";
import moment from "moment";
import "moment/min/locales";

const deviceLocale = getDeviceLocale();

moment.locale(deviceLocale); //set your locale (eg: fr)
moment(1316116057189).fromNow(); // il y a 7 ans
```

*Sharing this to those who need it*